# How use property control as bin pruner

Tags: spotfire

In a crosstable, I have [DATE] as a Year.Month bin. I created property control (let's call it ${DATEPRUNER} ). The property control is a drop-down with fixed options of 0 or 1. I tried inserting the property control where the 0 or 1 bin level is on the custom expression axis but I get the 'continuous expression not allowed...' error.

without prop control = BinByDateTime([DATE],"Year.Month",0)

what I tried = BinByDateTime([DATE],"Year.Month",${DATEPRUNER})

Answer (score 0):

when I tried it, it said 'a continuous expression is not allowed. Try wrapping it with < and >'. I did that and it worked.

```
<BinByDateTime([Date],'Year.Month',${datepruner}) as [mycustexp]>
```

It threw the same error when I used a straight 0 or 1 instead of the property control ${datepruner}. The cross table will want to display years and months as categorical values.

Gaia